# Looping through multiple CSV's and creating a dataframe of all them combined

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create a data frame using multiple `CSV` files. For this, I created a `for` loop but it only runs once. All data is already downloaded in `CSV` format.

```py
csvs = [
    "2014-2015.csv",
    "2015-2016.csv",
    "2016-2017.csv",
    "2017-2018.csv",
    "2018-2019.csv",
    "2019-2020.csv",
    "2020-2021.csv",
    "2021-2022.csv"
]
 
for csv in csvs: 
    data = pd.read_csv(csv)
    data_final = pd.DataFrame()
    data_final = data_final.append(data)
```

Comment: You seem to be (re-)creating your "final" dataframe inside the loop, effectively throwing away the previously created df in the next iteration. Move the creation before the loop.

Comment: The following link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with a comprehension like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

csv_files = [
    '2014-2015.csv',
    '2015-2016.csv',
    '2016-2017.csv',
    '2017-2018.csv',
    '2018-2019.csv',
    '2019-2020.csv',
    '2020-2021.csv',
    '2021-2022.csv'
]

combined_df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(_) for _ in csv_files])
```

Answer (score 0):

You must append your csv files as a dataframe and then merge them

```python
csvs = [ "2014-2015.csv", "2015-2016.csv", "2016-2017.csv", "2017-2018.csv", "2018-2019.csv", "2019-2020.csv", "2020-2021.csv", "2021-2022.csv" ]

list_of_dataframes = []
for filename in csvs :
    list_of_dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

merged_df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)

print(merged_df)
```